# Having trouble understanding what ">>" and "&" are doing in this BASH line

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to debug a script written for use in BASH.  I am a little confused as to what the following line is doing.

```
ffmpeg -threads 1 -f yuv4mpegpipe -i ./tmp/dvd-slideshow_temp_3203/dvdss-pipe-3203 -target ntsc-dvd -r 29.97 -an -aspect 4:3 -s 480 -y -bf 2 -f mpeg2video ./tmp/dvd-slideshow_temp_3203/video.mpg >> /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

the bit that really has me confused is the last bit:

```
>> /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I would be grateful if someone could tell me what this line is doing.

Comment: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/06/what-does-devnull-21-mean/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `>>` indicates that you want to redirect (append) the output of the command to something.
In your case you want to append the output to `/dev/null`.

The next part `2>&1` means that you are redirecting the **standard error pipe** to the **standard output pipe**. The final `&` indicates that you want to sent your command to the background.

The following would do the same `2>> /dev/null 1>> /dev/null &` but as you can see it's longer and not as readable as yours.

Answer (score 4):

There are three things happening in your posted line.

This appends the stdout to /dev/null:

```
>> /dev/null
```

Here, file descriptor 2 (stderr) is directed to file descriptor 1 (stdout). Since bash processes redirection from right to left, it is important that this comes after the stdout redirection.

```
2>&1
```

Last, the `&` runs the command in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

```
>>/dev/null
```

this redirects the standard output of the process to the null device. Since dev/null discards all data written to it you are just discarding the standard output. You can use a different file here instead if you feel like it

```
2>&1
```

this says: redirect standard error likewise. So you are also chucking away the error stream

and finally:

```
&
```

This detatches the process from the terminal instance. try this to see how it works:

```
gedit
```

and

```
gedit &
```

Comment: "detatches the process from the terminal instance" -- not quite, that's what `nohup` is for. The `&` pushes the job in the background, but when the terminal instance is closed, so is the job.